# Relative extrema of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I want to find and classify stationary points of $f(x,y)=(x - 5)^2(y - 2)^2$.

I use an algorithm described here: [Section 3-3 : Relative Minimums And Maximums](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/RelativeExtrema.aspx)

$$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2(x-5)(y-2)^2=0\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2(x-5)^2(y-2)=0\end{cases}$$

This system has infinitely many solutions of the form $(5, y_0)$ and $(x_0, 2)$.

Now, let's try to classify these stationary points.

$D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-\left(f_{xy}\right)^2=-12(x-5)^2(y-2)^2$

But $D(5,y_0)=0$ and $D(x_0,2)=0$, so the stationary points can't be classified. Is there some algorithm for finding a relative minimum $(5,2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a general analytic algorithm to classify the nature of critical points when second partial derivative test fails. In this case, by inspection, all the points $(5, y_0)$ and $(x_0, 2)$ are points of global minima for the function which are also (non-strict) saddle points.